# jQuery Select2 - Highlighting the child (when the search term matches) instead of its parent in hierarchical list

Tags: jquery-select2

Select2 3.5.2.

I have some hierarchical data in a select2 list where the parents AND children are all valid selections. If possible, when the search term matches a child, I'd like the child to be highlighted by default instead of the parent.

For example, given the following code...

```
$("#hdn").select2(
{
    width: '300px',
    data:
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Italy',
            children:
            [
                { id: 2, text: 'Italy - Sardinia' },
                { id: 3, text: 'Italy - Sicily' },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            text: 'United Kingdom',
            children:
            [
                { id: 5, text: 'United Kingdom - Guernsey' },
                { id: 6, text: 'United Kingdom - Jersey' }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

... if you start typing 'Jer', it currently highlights 'United Kingdom' by default:

[image: Current Behaviour]

Ideally, if you start typing 'Jer', it should highlight 'United Kingdom - Jersey' by default instead.

Because this is a group I still want the parent to show as an option, I just want the child to be highlighted by default instead.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moo_ski_doo/atnph13b/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 will highlight the first option which is selectable by default. If you don't want the highlight to sit on "United Kingdom" first, you are going to have to remove the `id`.

Select2 3.5.2 does not provide an easy way to change how what option is highlighted by default.

Comment: I thought that might be the case - thanks for confirming. We might have to resort to making the parents unselectable and having 'Mainland United Kingdom' and 'Mainland Italy' as children too. I'll accept your answer if no-one can come up with another suggestion.

Comment: @Moo That's highly recommended, it's more in-line with a standard `<select>`.